# NavigationView item text alignment

Tags: android

i can't make text alignment to the the items in

android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

i tried this but not work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:title="@string/do" />
        </group>

</menu>
```

so should i use listview instead of menu items to have text alignment ?

i tried to write arabic words and it's gravity is right as i want 
this is the solution but is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with styles and change attributes in navigationView itself but not in menu items. Its look like you truing to change items in menu, but not the view.